# Dynamically loaded items not shown in second time on dropdown (Harvesthq Chosen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-select, jquery-chosen

I'm using this following tool to make the dropdown searchable and look nice.

[Harvesthq Chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen)

First I'm loading the data dynamically in dropdown and applying this code to apply the effect.

```
 $(".chosen-select").chosen();
```

It works just fine. Everything ok. Then depending on some option I want to **empty** all data and **insert** new options. Now problems occur. The newly added options are not shown. Old options are still visible.

So I checked with the **firebug**. `Select` tag contains my desired data, but it's showing wrong data(Old ones).Some kind of `div` is visible. I tried to apply the `chosen` methd once again. But not working. Then I tried

```
$("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

And not working either. Can anybody tell me what is missing?

I want to clear and load data dynamically multiple times in dropdown and apply the **chosen** effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
$("#form_field").trigger("liszt:updated");
```